# App stops working when calling Http.PostAsync when returning a string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor

I have a Blazor app that's calling a WebAPI method that returns a string, however when it runs, it just stops. The app remains open but nothing appears to happen.

When i put a breakpoint in the controller it does run.

```
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
await file.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);

status = $"Finished loading {file.Size} bytes from {file.Name}";

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent {
  { new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer()), "\"upload\"", file.Name }
};

string featureImage = await Http.PostAsync("api/Blog/ReturnString", content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Above is the code that calls the WebAPI method. Below is the Controller that returns a very simple string.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> ReturnString()
{
    return "123456";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should to return a `Task<string>` instead an `string`. Try with `return Task.FromResult("1234");`. Also, press F12 o. browser (devtolols) and check for errors on dev console and on network activity if this is wasm or use debug on server side. Also, this `Http` from where comes? Please, try to isolate issue before post questions.

Comment: Please, comment out the [Authorize] attribute because your code does not seems to be passing any credentials. Perhaps the issue is related to this. If not, you should display all your code. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the comment by @enet, there're likely two more bugs:

1. There's a risk of dead lock in the way you get `Result` by using `.Result.Content`. You need change the code to `await ...`
2. Also, if you're using Blazor Server side, be aware that invoking `Http` in Blazor ServerSide App is different from the Blazor WebAssembly App. You need create your own HttpClient or inject one and then provide base uri for it.

Hope the below helps:

(if you're using Blazor ServerSide) register `HttpClient` related services in your startup:

```
services.AddHttpClient();   // only if you're using Blazor ServerSide
```

And within your Blazor component/page:

```
@using System.Net.Http              
@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory   @*if you're using Blazor ServerSide*@
@inject NavigationManager navMgr               @*if you're using Blazor ServerSide*@


@code{
    var Http = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();    //if you're using Blazor ServerSide
    Http.BaseAddress = new Uri(navMgr.BaseUri);     //if you're using Blazor ServerSide
    // ... add credentials if you're using Blazor ServerSide

    //... your code

    // don't block it by access the`.Result` property, await it!
    await Http.PostAsync("api/Blog/ReturnString", content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var resp= await Http.PostAsync("api/Blog/ReturnString", content);
    var featureImage = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Finally, if above code doesn't address the problem, could you please Press `F12` within the browser and show us the error message ?

Comment: It was this part that resolved the issue - var resp= await Http.PostAsync("api/Blog/ReturnString", content);
    var featureImage = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();